# solution of first order partial differential equation $(x^2+y^2)p+yq=z+x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the first ordered differential equation 
\begin{equation}
(x^2+y^2)p+yq=z+x^2.
\end{equation}
I am trying to solve the equations 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z+x^2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).